# Python counting keyboard interrupts

Tags: python

```
s = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
os.wait()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, s)
```

Currently, I have the above code. This working fine for me at the moment if someone wants to press insane amount of `Ctrl+c`

But I want to have an arbitrary count instead of continually ignoring it as the above. For example, I want to `sys.exit()` instead of let `os.wait()` keep going if I receive 5 `Ctrl+c`.

So how can i count `ctrl+c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signal` can accept a functor:

```
import signal
import sys

class S:
    cnt = 0

    def __call__(self, signum, frame):
        self.cnt += 1
        if (self.cnt == 5):
            sys.exit()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, S())
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a", line 730, in <module>
    os.wait()
OSError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call

 on the second ctrl c

Comment: `os.wait()` (and many other blocking functions) throw `OSError` with `errno.EINTR` on any non-ignored interrupt. You need to check for that in your code. In C, you could use `SA_RESTART` but in Python, this cannot be done because the way Python handles signals would make the signal handler never called.

Comment: maybe i should just have signal handler inside the process that it is waiting on?

Comment: or is there an alternatives to os.wait?

Comment: Just restart `os.wait()` on `EINTR`.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need a variable that you increase and compare to five.

EDIT: I did not assume you were able to handle signals but not able to introduce a python variable, but oh well:

```
counter = 0
def handle_sigint(signal_number, _frame):
     if counter >= 5:
          sys.exit(-1) #or whatever you want
     else:
          counter += 1

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_sigint)
```

Comment: well yes. how do i do that?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a", line 730, in <module>
    os.wait()
OSError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call

 on the second ctrl c